# Bundle from main activity to fragment

Tags: android

i m following some guide to pass parameter from login to one fragment.
I have this structure (login page, user area (main activity that cointain only a fragment and some fragment) 
I try to do this :

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    //super.onBackPressed();
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.anto.fitfix.R.layout.activity_user_area);






  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    final String name = b.getString("name");
    final String user = b.getString("id");
    final String email = b.getString("email");
    final String gender = b.getString("gender");
    final String photourl= b.getString("photo");
    final String birthday = b.getString("birthday");
    final String p="null";


    Log.d("nome",""+name);



   // loadFragment(new fragment_home());

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("name", 123);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new fragment_home()).commit();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);







    }
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        fragment_home fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                fragment = new fragment_home();
                break;

            case R.id.action_cron:
                fragment = new fragment_home();
                break;

            case R.id.action_face:
               // fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;


        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
private boolean loadFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

and this for fragment

```
public class fragment_home extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String name,email,user,p;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        TextView tResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tResult);
        TextView tMail = (TextView) view.findViewById(com.example.anto.fitfix.R.id.tMail);
        TextView tAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tAge);


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {

            int myInt = bundle.getInt("name");
            Log.d("name",""+myInt);
            tResult.setText(name);
        }





        BLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setMessage("wait..."); // Setting Message
                progressDialog.setTitle("Logout"); // Setting Title
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
                progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            disconnectFromFacebook();
                            Thread.sleep(1600);
                            Intent fbIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                            getActivity().startActivity(fbIntent);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }).start();


            }
        });

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

      /*  FbActivity registerRequest = new FbActivity(name, user, p, email, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(registerRequest);*/

        return view;
    }






}
```

I recived the name from login , but i cant pass in fragment section..
Someone can give me the suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a bundle to fragment, you do not create an object of `Fragment` class, but instead you create the object of the *fragment* you created i.e `fragment_home`

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt("name", 123);
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new fragment_home()).commit();
```

Change the above code with the code below

```
 fragment_home fragment = new fragment_home();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("name", 123);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: thanks so much! worked!  I got the error , i tried many times, but my real problem that i never used "(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)" where fragment meaning the new object of fragment_home.